# Search for a partial string in a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of strings looking like this:

```
['MEASUREMENT   K02313  New York',\
 'MEASUREMENT   K02338  London [BC:2.7.7.7]',\
 'MEASUREMENT   K14761  Kairo [BC:1.2.-.-]',\
 'MEASUREMENT   K03629  Berlin',\
 'MEASUREMENT   K02470  Paris [BC:5.6.2.-]',\
 'MEASUREMENT   K02469  Madrid [BC:5.43.2.2]',\
....]
```

As you can see some elements in the list have a string with the format **BC:x.x.x.x**, with x either being a number from 0-999 or a hyphen ("-").
Now I want to get a seperate list that has all of these BC:x.x.x.x elements saved.
I tried using a regular expression:

```
re.findall(r"BC:([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|-).([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|-).([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|-).([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|-)", list_name)
```

but it doesn't work, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: I think it is a tuple of strings not a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're currently passing a tuple of strings to the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method. If you want to use a single command, then transform your tuple of strings into a single string:

```
re.findall(r"BC:[\d\.]+", ' '.join(list_name))
```

Comment: It is inefficient to join the entire list and then run find all.

Comment: Don't think so, I've just carried out some performance tests between mine and your solution. Have you? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are passing an array to findall function, try iterating through every element of that array and pass it to findall function.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension along with `re.search`:

```py
inp = ['MEASUREMENT   K02313  New York', 'MEASUREMENT   K02338  London [BC:2.7.7.7]', 'MEASUREMENT   K14761  Kairo [BC:1.2.-.-]', 'MEASUREMENT   K03629  Berlin', 'MEASUREMENT   K02470  Paris [BC:5.6.2.-]', 'MEASUREMENT   K02469  Madrid [BC:5.43.2.2]']
output = [re.search(r'\[BC:.*?\]', x).group() for x in inp if '[BC:' in x]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['[BC:2.7.7.7]', '[BC:1.2.-.-]', '[BC:5.6.2.-]', '[BC:5.43.2.2]']
```

Comment: I only want the BC:x.x.x.x elements saved, so a list that looks like this ['BC:2.7.7.7', 'BC:1.2.-.-', ...]. That is what is giving me trouble because I don't know if there is a function that makes this possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your pattern without capture groups as you only want the match.

Then per item in the list get the match using a list comprehension (assuming there is 1 BC: item between square brackets)

The pattern can be shortened with a quantifier `{3}` repeating the dot and a number 0-999 without a leading zeroes and there can be one alternative less by adding the hyphen to the first character class `[a-z-]`

```
\bBC:(?:[0-9-]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])(?:\.(?:[0-9-]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])){3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymNf4Z/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pnRpDY)

```
import re

lst = ['MEASUREMENT   K02313  New York',
       'MEASUREMENT   K02338  London [BC:2.7.7.7]',
       'MEASUREMENT   K14761  Kairo [BC:1.2.-.-]',
       'MEASUREMENT   K03629  Berlin',
       'MEASUREMENT   K02470  Paris [BC:5.6.2.-]',
       'MEASUREMENT   K02469  Madrid [BC:5.43.2.2]'
       ]
pattern = r"\bBC:(?:[0-9-]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])(?:\.(?:[0-9-]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])){3}"

print ([m.group() for s in lst for m in [re.search(pattern, s)] if m])
```

Output

```
['BC:2.7.7.7', 'BC:1.2.-.-', 'BC:5.6.2.-', 'BC:5.43.2.2']
```